# What does the math symbol $\propto$ mean?

Tags: notation

I came across this symbol in my engineering class and I have never seen it before. Anyone know this?

[image]

Comment: Well.. More like reading it in my book and came across it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It typically means proportional to. Such that

If $$y=cx$$ for some constant $c$ we say

$$y\propto x$$ so that when x grows, y grows *proportionally* by the ratio $c$

Alternatively *inverse proportionality* is when

$$y=c\frac{1}{x}$$ so that when x gets smaller, y gets bigger *proportionally* by $c$

$$y\propto \frac{1}{x}$$ to my knowledge there isn’t a symbol specifically for inverse proportionality and $$y\propto \frac{1}{x}$$ is used instead

Comment: Is there a symbol for inverse proportionality as well?

Comment: No I don’t think so typically $$y\propto \frac{1}{x}$$ is used

Comment: This solved my question. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, this symbol means "is proportional to."  That is, $$a \propto b$$ means that there is some constant $C$ such that
$$a = Cb.$$

That being said, in the interests of "teaching a man to fish", it is worth pointing out that it is often possible to "reverse engineer" the meaning of specific mathematical symbols using [DeTeXify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).  In this case, drawing the mysterious symbol gives

[image]

Either `\propto` or `\varpropto` seems to give the correct symbol.  TeX often uses "var" to indicate a variation of a symbol (for example `\epsilon` $\epsilon$ vs `\varepsilon` $\varepsilon$; `\theta` $\theta$ vs `\vartheta` $\vartheta$), so "propto" seems like a reasonable guess as to what this symbol should be called.  [Googling this term](https://www.google.com/search?q=propto) gives a large number of results, many of which are relevant.

Comment: This is awesome! I'll use this in the future if I come across more mystic symbols!

Comment: Glad I could be of use.  Honestly, DeTeXify is one of my favorite things on the interwebs.  There is also a free-to-use desktop version (you can pay something like 8 bucks to remove shareware reminders, if you desire---I think it is worth it to support a snazzy bit of hardware).

Answer (score 0):

$\propto$ means "proportional to."

Answer (score 0):

This symbol is often used, primarily in physics, to denote direct proportionality. so the RHS and LHS of your expression only differ by some scalar multiple.